# If $\sin A + \cos A + \tan A + \cot A + \sec A + \csc A = 7$ then $x^2 - 44x - 36 = 0$ holds for $x=\sin 2A$

Tags: trigonometry

If 
$$\sin A + \cos A + \tan A + \cot A + \sec A + \csc A = 7$$
then prove that 
$$\sin 2A \quad\text{ is a root of }\quad x^2 - 44x - 36 = 0$$

I have no idea how to solve it. Plz help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$\sin{A}+\cos{A}=t$$

$$7=\sin A+\cos A+\frac{1}{\sin A\cos A}+\frac{\sin A+\cos A} {\sin A\cos A}$$

$$\sin 2A =2 \sin A \cos A$$

$$t^2=1+\sin 2A$$

Comment: Can u plz elaborate?

Comment: @user36790 Done.

Comment: Will I have to pair tan & cot and sec & cosec ?

Comment: @user36790 Yes.

Comment: Why have u taken t?Will i have to substitute sinxcosx in terms of t?Do u want to find the value of t?

Comment: @user36790 It's just a substitution. Form an equation in t and finally substitute everything in terms of $\sin 2A$

Comment: The value of sin2x is 8 but it doesn't satisfy the equation?

Comment: @user36790 sin is always between -1 and 1. You can eliminate this root by dividing by sin(2x)-8 in the polynomial.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14227/discussion-between-user36790-and-awesome)

Comment: Plz show me the division,sir?

Comment: @user36790 What equation(s) have you got?

Comment: @user36790 Post them and I will guide you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the problem wrong, you can show $\sin 2A$ is a root of $x^2-44x+36$ using Awesome's hint.

EDIT:

If $\sin 2A$ is a root of $x^2-44x+36$, then 
$$\sin 2A = \frac{44 \pm \sqrt{1936 - 144}}{2}=22\pm 8\sqrt{7}$$

Since $|\sin 2A|\leq 1$, we have that $\sin 2A = 22-8\sqrt{7}$.

Using the hint by Awesome,

\begin{align}
7 &=\sin A + \cos A + \frac{1}{\sin A\cos A} + \frac{\sin A + \cos A}{\sin A\cos A} \\
&= t + \frac{1+t}{\frac{1}{2}(t^2-1)} \\
&= t + \frac{2(1+t)}{t^2-1} \\
&= t + \frac{2}{t-1}. \end{align}

This gives the polynomial $t^2-8t+9=0$, which has roots $t=4 \pm \sqrt{7}$.  Since $$(\sin A + \cos A)^2 = 1+\sin 2A \leq 1 + 1= 2,$$ we have $$|\sin A + \cos A| \leq \sqrt{2}.$$

This forces $t=4-\sqrt{7}$.  You can now compute $\sin 2A = 22-8\sqrt{7}$ as desired.

Comment: Are u sure bcuz i ve taken it from a trusted mathbook ensured by the govt education board?Obviously u r right as i ve applied the above mentioned method but in vain.

Comment: Yes,u r right.Thanks for the marking of the error.

Comment: Can u plz show me the division to eliminate the root as mentioned by Awesome?

Comment: Sure, I will edit my answer.