# Solving trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics, radicals, substitution

> If we have $$\sin (A) +\cos (A) + \csc (A) + \sec (A) +\tan (A) +\cot (A)= 7$$ and
>   $$\sin(2A) =a-b\sqrt{7}= 2\sin(A)\cos(A).$$
>   What values can $a$ and $b$ take?

Comment: Where did you find this problem?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $a$ and $b$? Do they have to be integers or can they be any real number?

Comment: Nilknarf My Mathematics teacher gave it to me

Comment: Maybe this post might help: [If $\sin A + \cos A + \tan A + \cot A + \sec A + \csc A = 7$ then $x^2 - 44x - 36 = 0$ holds for $x=\sin 2A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/775269)? Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csin%20(A)%20%2B%5Ccos%20(A)%20%2B%20%5Ccsc%20(A)%20%2B%20%5Csec%20(A)%20%2B%5Ctan%20(A)%20%2B%5Ccot%20(A)%3D%207%24&p=1).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371463/solving-two-trigonometric-equations-with-three-variables

Answer (score 3):

Let $A=x$ and  $\sin{x}+\cos{x}=t$.

Hence, $|t|\leq\sqrt2$, $\sin{x}\cos{x}=\frac{t^2-1}{2}$ and we need to solve
$$t+\frac{t}{\frac{t^2-1}{2}}+\frac{1}{\frac{t^2-1}{2}}=7$$ or
$$t+\frac{2}{t-1}=7$$ or
$$t^2-8t+9=0$$ or
$$(t-4)^2=7,$$ which gives
$t=4+\sqrt7$, which is impossible, or $t=4-\sqrt7$,

which gives $\sin2x=t^2-1=(4-\sqrt7)^2-1=22-8\sqrt7$.

Id est, $a=22$ and $b=8$ if you mean that $a$ and $b$ are naturals.

Done!

Comment: I still did'nt understand one thing that why is |t|  less than equal to √2 ? Could you please give me a simple explanation

Comment: @Albert Pinto because $\sin{x}+\cos{x}=\sqrt2\left(\sin{x}\cos45^{\circ}+\cos{x}\sin45^{\circ}\right)=\sqrt2\sin\left(x+45^{\circ}\right)$ and $-1\leq \sin\leq1$.

Comment: @Albert Pinto Also there is the following explanation. Let $\sin{x}=a$ and $\cos{x}=b$. Hence, $a^2+b^2=1$ and we need to prove that $|a+b|\leq\sqrt2$ or $(a+b)^2\leq2$ or $(a+b)^2\leq2(a^2+b^2)$ or $(a-b)^2\geq0$, which is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$\sin(2A)=22-8\sqrt{7}$$